# Unable to Shutdown or Hibernate Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, bios, shutdown, hibernate

I just had the fans in my laptop replaced as they had got spoilt and since then, for some reason, I haven't been able to shutdown or hibernate my laptop from within Windows. I tried a few things, one of them was using the command

```
powercfg /h off
```

Which then allowed me to shutdown from within Windows, but then I realized what it was actually doing was removing the hibernate feature, which I use on a daily basis so I cannot afford to lose.

Here is exactly what happens:

1. When I press shutdown from the start menu, it spirals around a bit and takes me back to the lock screen.
2. I have configured my system such that when I hit the power button or close the lid, the system hibernates, but now instead it takes me back to the lock screen.
3. When I type `shutdown /h /t 0` into CMD, it spirals around a bit and takes me back to the lock screen.

However, `shutdown -s` from CMD does work.

I had noticed that my BIOS settings were reset when I got the laptop back from service, so maybe something has changed there? Either way, any help would be appreciated!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can try the BIOS power options. It's possible your Windows power options were also reset. If it's not a software, then something is wrong with the hardware.

Comment: What's the OS version of your windows 10 client? Is Fast Startup enabled? Please kindly check if this link is helpful:https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3211190/fast-startup-causes-hibernation-or-shutdown-to-fail-in-windows-10-wind

Comment: Windows Version 2004 and Fast Startup is already disabled.